# What is this frame feature for?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I have a [Kinesis Tripster ATR](http://www.kinesisbikes.co.uk/Catalogue/Models/Adventure/Tripster-ATR).  The drive-side seat stay has a lug on it whose purpose I can't work out:

[image: Seat-stay lug]

There's no such feature on the other seat stay.  What is it for?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Its a chain hanger.  Purpose is to hold the chain when you take the wheel off.

The idea is to support the chain and stop it falling through itself, making a tight loop and shortening the life of those links.

They're not common on carbon bikes any more, but handy on any working bike.

Don't forget to undo the chain after reinstalling the wheel and before riding away.

Comment: Thanks – I thought it might be something like that.  It doesn't seem to hold the chain very well, though!

Comment: Yeah its only a convenience thing - personally I don't use it when removing wheel on the road bike.  (9 punctures this half-year - I'm getting quite good at changing tubes now!)